# Why a ~ in double quotes within awk caused syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I was going write script for my device.
Here is my initial code:

```
dev_name=random_sting
major=`awk "\$2 ~ /^${dev_name}\$/ { print \$1 }" /proc/devices`
```

Then an error happen

```
awk:  ~ /^random_string$/ { print  }
awk:  ^ syntax error
```

Meanwhile, I did an experiment:

```
var1=random_string
echo "\$ /^$var1\$/ \$"
```

The output was

```
$ /^random_string$/ $
```

It seems the syntax should be correct, can anybody give me an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solve the problem.
Let's scrutinize this line:

```
dev_name='loop' ; major=` awk "\\\$2 ~ /^\${dev_name}\\\$/ { print \\\$1 }" /proc/devices` ; echo $major
```

bash expand it twice, and double quote is not expanded between backticks (`), so this is going to output the proper outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need additional escapes inside back ticks. Try using `major=$( .. )` instead..

Comment: No, you need to use single quotes, not double, to delimit your awk script. See @user0001's answer.

Comment: He could do that too, or do both. I too would use single quotes, but if he would like to use double quotes that way then changing backticks to `$( .. )` should be sufficient to make it work..

Comment: Using double quotes is absolutely the wrong thing to do. It makes your script much more complicated, difficult to enhance and future, and error prone vs just using single quotes.

Comment: I do use single quotes instead, but, I just ponder what incurs the syntax error, since it looks quite right to me.

Comment: Where is it in your post? Or are you referring to the command the was given in one of the answers? What is the exact command you are using ? What syntax error do you get? What is the content of the variable you are testing with?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can also bypass the need for escaping, using the `-v` option of `awk`, like this

```
major=`awk -v dev="$dev_name" '$2 ~ dev { print $1 }' /proc/devices`
```

Comment: +1 This is THE correct answer. Double quote your shell variable though: `dev="$devname"`.

Comment: This is a gracious method which I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression inside backticks will pass through 2 shells/unescape stages.

```
awk "\$2 ~ /^${dev_name}\$/ { print \$1 }" /proc/devices
```

...will be expanded and unescaped by your bash to...

```
awk "$2 ~ /^random_string$/ { print $1 }" /proc/devices`
```

...which the shell started by the backticks will expand and unescape again to...

```
awk "~ /^random_string$/ { print  }" /proc/devices`
```

...since $1 and $2 are not defined.

What you want to do is to escape $1 and $2 twice;

```
awk "\\\$2 ~ /^${dev_name}\$/ { print \\\$1 }" /proc/devices
```

...to make the executed end result...

```
awk "$2 ~ /^random_string\$/ { print $1 }" /proc/devices
```

Comment: don't do this. ever. pass the value of the shell variable to awk by assigning it to an awk variable and put your script in single quotes.

Comment: However, I accidentally write the command into awk "\\$2 ~ /^${dev_name}\$/ { print \\$1 }" /proc/devices, it also works, that confused me... Why it didn't expand $1 and $2 at the first place.

Comment: @dspjm - "this approach works fine". Really? You're happy having to escape various characters multiple times and exposing yourself to the shells globbing, word splitting, and file name expansion as well as having obscure syntax errors? OK, glad you got a solution that works for you.

Comment: I didn't use this method at all, though I want to know what happened, it concerns the mechanism bash works, which actually fascinates me.